# How to GROUP by month & year with an epoch timestamp in AWS Redshift

Tags: group-by, timestamp, redshift

Assuming a very simple schema as pictured below. (unfortunately the column is actually named `timestamp`)

How do I simply get a count on records grouped by YEAR & MONTH

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
select 
extract(MONTH FROM date(timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp / 1 * interval '1 second')) as month,
extract(YEAR FROM date(timestamp 'epoch' + timestamp / 1 * interval '1 second')) as year,
count(*)
from audit_logs
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrew for your answer. Wondering is there anyway to group by weeks ?